# Assessing performance of a generative model (images) using Jensen-Shannon Divergence

Tags: pca, generative-models, mnist

#### Background

I am currently working on comparing two high-dimensional image datasets (MNIST) of shape $\sim(50000, 256)$ to evaluate the performance of a generative model, and have attempted to use Principal Component Analysis (PCA) as a preprocessing step to reduce dimensionality, (from 256 to 4) before computing the Jensen-Shannon Divergence (JSD) using histograms. With this approach the resulting JSD values appear to be insensitive to the underlying differences in sample quality. I am pretty sure that the problem is performing PCA from 256 dims to 4, which erases almost all information.

#### Question

What is a good way to compute JSD between two datasets if the dimensions are too big to compute histograms directly?